# why is racket code returning void : Sudoku

Tags: racket, void, sudoku

```
(define (solver row col board boolboard) ;solve the game
  (if (equal? row 9)      
  board           
  (if (equal? (get-value boolboard row col) #t)          
      (begin            
        (for ([ite '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)]) ;true              
          (when (equal? (check-available row col ite board) #t) ;should be careful here                
            (begin                  
              (let ([new-board (set-value board row col ite)])
                (if (equal? col 8)
                    (solver (+ 1 row) 0 new-board boolboard)
                    (solver row (+ 1 col) new-board boolboard)))
              )          
          )
        ))      
      (if (and (equal? col 8) (equal? row 8)) ;false
          board
          (if (equal? col 8)

              (solver (+ 1 row) 0 board boolboard)

              (solver row (+ 1 col) board boolboard)

          )))
  )
  )
```

This is the soduku solver. I've checked that the solver finally reached (if (equal? row 9) so it gets the board. But the function still returns #. I dont know why it is not returning the board.

Anyone could help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

A general rule for fixing these types of bugs:

If it's returning something you don't expect (here, `#<void>`), then look for the cases in your function that could return that. You determined that the base case returns what you expect, but you have to check the other cases too.

The next case has a `begin` with a [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29) inside of it. The [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29) form always returns `#<void>` no matter what the body expression returned on any iteration.

So there's your case where it's returning `#<void>`. The [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29) form evaluates the body of the loop on each iteration, but ignores the return values.

Because of this, [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29) is pretty much never what you want. Normally forms like [`for/list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29), [`for/or`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2For%29%29), and [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29) are much more useful. In this case, [`for/first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29) looks like it could be what you meant.

If you translate it blindly,

```
(for/first ([ite '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)])
  (when (equal? (check-available row col ite board) #t)
    (let ([new-board (set-value board row col ite)])
      (if (equal? col 8)
          (solver (+ 1 row) 0 new-board boolboard)
          (solver row (+ 1 col) new-board boolboard)))))
```

Then this still doesn't work because it still returns `#<void>` a lot of the time, since the `when` form returns `#<void>` when the condition is false. The [`for/first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29) form isn't magic. It doesn't see that the when form fails or use that information to go to the next clause. To make [`for/first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29) check the condition and go on to the next clause if it's false, use a `#:when` clause after the `[ite ...]`.

```
(for/first ([ite '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)]
            #:when (equal? (check-available row col ite board) #t))
  (let ([new-board (set-value board row col ite)])
    (if (equal? col 8)
        (solver (+ 1 row) 0 new-board boolboard)
        (solver row (+ 1 col) new-board boolboard))))
```

The [`for/first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29) form will evaluate the body for the first iteration where the `#:when` condition is true, and return that.

However, if the `#:when` condition is never true for any iteration, the [`for/first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29) form will return false, so that will cause your `solver` function to return false.

But that means that the recursive calls within the [`for/first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29) form could return false. If that happens, what should it do? You probably want to go to the next iteration of the loop. For that, you can use [`for/or`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2For%29%29), which is similar to [`for/first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29), except that it goes on to the next iteration if the body returns false.

```
(for/or ([ite '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)]
         #:when (equal? (check-available row col ite board) #t))
  (let ([new-board (set-value board row col ite)])
    (if (equal? col 8)
        (solver (+ 1 row) 0 new-board boolboard)
        (solver row (+ 1 col) new-board boolboard))))
```

That way, if filling in one number doesn't end up yielding a solution and it returns false, it can try the next number.

This solves your question about it returning `#<void>`. If there are more problems with your code, you should ask another question.

Comment: Thank you for answering! My new problem is, after I replace my code with yours, the "(if (equal? row 9))" clause is never reached. So the program still return #f. Could you please tell me the reason

Comment: You should ask a new question, with a complete example of it doing something you didn't expect. But first look at your code and see if it's really structured in a way that would yield good solutions.

Comment: It might be that for/or is more useful for this case, because it acts like for/first except that it goes to the next iteration if the body returns false. Also, for each recursive call you should consider what should happen if it returns false, and whether it can/should try a "next" potential solution.

Comment: Does `for/or` do what you expect? Does it get to the `(if (equal row 9) board ...)` case?